# How to create a calendar object based on current time plus some seconds

Tags: java

I am wondering if I can get a new Calendar object based on current time plus a given timespan, say 5 minutes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); //gives u calendar with current time
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5); //add 5 minutes to calendar
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [add](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) function of Calendar class for adding and `setTime(new Date())` for getting calendar based on current time.

Comment: For anyone coming acroos his. Don't do it. This is a deprecated way of setting the date of the calendar. And my program acted weird if I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You got to use c.set() methods to set year, month and date for the calendar object.